# Saving NSImage to path doesn't work

Tags: swift, macos, save, nsfilemanager, nsimage

The macOS program I'm working on loads an image through a dialog, then crops and previews it to the user. It should now save the image back to the folder of the path where it was originally loaded from. I've tried saving the image data via the `.write(to: URL)` method and the NSFileManager. Neither did work.

Output:

```
file:///Users/username/Downloads/test.png
File creation failed
```

Code:

```
@IBAction func browseFile(_ sender: NSButton) {
    let dialog = NSOpenPanel();

    dialog.title                   = "Choose an image file";
    dialog.showsResizeIndicator    = true;
    dialog.showsHiddenFiles        = false;
    dialog.canChooseDirectories    = true;
    dialog.canCreateDirectories    = true;
    dialog.allowsMultipleSelection = true;
    dialog.allowedFileTypes        = ["jpg","jpeg","png"];

    if (dialog.runModal() == NSApplication.ModalResponse.OK) {
        let result = dialog.url // Pathname of the file

        if (result != nil) {

            // "result" is the path of the image selected via the dialog
            let corrected: NSImage = cutImage(image: NSImage(contentsOf: result!)!) // crop image
            imageView.image = corrected // show cropped image preview

            // save cropped image to disk
            let fileName = "test"
            let fileManager = FileManager.default
            let fileURL = result!.deletingLastPathComponent().appendingPathComponent("\(fileName).png") // set url to the same folder as where the image was loaded from
            print(fileURL)
            if let pngImageData = corrected.PNGRepresentation {
                //try? pngImageData.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)
                fileManager.createFile(atPath: fileURL.path, contents: pngImageData, attributes: nil)
                if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) {
                    print("File successfully saved")
                } else {
                    print("File creation failed")
                }
            }

        }
    } else {
        // User clicked on "Cancel"
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: See TARGETS > App Sandbox > File Access.

Comment: This worked! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

[Enabling Read-Write Permissions in Capabilities -> File Access solved the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qB7T.png)

Answer (score 0):

Probably due to the sandbox. Your app got permission to load `<folder>/originalfile.png` via the Open dialog, but doesn't have permission to save to `<folder>/test.png`. You will need to present the user with a Save dialog (can have the default filename pre-selected) to get permission to save the new file.